# Curl to call local file and close the connection after recieving 1st bit

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I have a file "ajax.php" that needs to trigger a big while loop and continue working not waiting for the big while loop to finish , so i put the while loop in while.php file , and need to call it using curl , any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running on Windows, you can use the curl_multi:

```
// create cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://domain/path/to/script");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

//add the handle
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch);

// execute the handle
curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);
```

But if you're running Linux, you may fork too:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) { // mother process
     // continue doing stuff here
     echo 'Child labor ';
     echo 'is acceptable ';
     echo 'in programming';

     // wait for the child to finish
     pcntl_wait($status);
 } else { // child process
     // do big loop here
     while (...) {
         sleep(1000);
     }
 }
```

Comment: the script will work for an hour inside a loop , will this curl trigger the loop and exit ? i don't want the connection to be established for more than 1 second

Comment: Well curl won't disconnect before the calling script (the fast-running one) exits. However, your called script (the slow-running one) might get killed by Apache when curl closes the connection.

Comment: Not actually when set_time_limit is set to zero and ignore_user_abort set to true

Comment: I didn't know about the ignore_user_abort. Thanks
!

Comment: I didn't know that either till i had to make custom cron jobs :p